# Cropping images instead of scaling with Plone and Archetypes

Tags: plone, archetypes

We'd like to crop images instead of scaling (Archetypes ImageField), so that the top left corner (or any corner) would be automatically displayed in given proportions.

What options / add-ons I have for this in Plone?

Comment: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.cropimage/ just crop on the fly, the original image stay untouched.  http://pypi.python.org/pypi/archetypes.clippingimage this clips it to fit a scale, http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.ImageEditor lets you edit an atimage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cropping images on the server-side and then maintaining blob copies of the images is too much pain.

Instead, just set the file upload limit with Archetypes validators to keep files reasonable small:

http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/content/archetypes/files.html#setting-max-file-size-to-filefield-and-imagefield

Then crop images using CSS.

Related css for top left crop:

```
.product-listing .info-box .main-image-wrapper {
    display: block;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    width: 280;
    height: 205px;
    padding: 10px;

    margin-bottom: 30px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #aaa, 0 5px 3px #aaa;

    transition: background 0.5s, box-shadow 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: background 0.5s, box-shadow 0.5s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: background 0.5s, box-shadow 0.5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: background 0.5s, box-shadow 0.5s; /* Opera */
}

.product-listing .info-box .main-image-container {
    display: block;
    width: 280px;
    height: 205px;
    background: transparent no-repeat top left;
}

.product-listing .info-box .main-image-wrapper:hover {
    background: #eee;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #aaa, 0 6px 5px #666;
}
```

Related TAL:

```
<a class="main-image-wrapper" tal:attributes="href python:view.getTargetLink(context)" tal:condition="python:getattr(product.aq_base, 'image', None) != None">
    <div class="main-image-container"
         tal:attributes="style string:background-image:url(${context/absolute_url}/@@images/image)"
         class="main-image">

         <!-- -->

    </div>

</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in the new addon [plone.app.imagecropping](https://github.com/collective/plone.app.imagecropping). It is based on ggozad's branch of plone.app.imaging and was factored out due to plone FTW decision (see plip [#10174](http://dev.plone.org/plone/ticket/10174)). Right now there is no release available but this will change in the near future.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Comment: Please cool down, Andrew. The answer is very useful and I don't see how it is self-promoting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any addons to achieve this; so I will answer: You have to develop it.

Answer (score 0):

I had started doing this for a client a while ago as a branch on p.a.imaging. It never got integrated, but hopefully you can use it almost as is:

https://github.com/plone/plone.app.imaging/tree/ggozad-cropping